SharePoint 2016 Userprofile import overwrite userprofile property for some users
In SharePoint 2016 I am using LDAP connectionstring for user profile import from AD. No manage properties are set to import. Default email and username is mapped to AD.
In our solution we are using user profile property "Title" which is not imported from AD. For most of users this property is added manually. For some users during import it set to empty. And in mapping it is not mapped to connectionstring. Import just set empty to few profiles not all of them. We also have some other managed properties which is not affected by import prosess.
I have deleted these users and have added data manually to. Still having same problem.
